# How to use Sweet Alert in ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, sweetalert

I am trying to use the sweet alert to use as a pop-up message in my ASP.NET C# application. But I think I am doing wrong because, If I click the button or Link button, nothing really happens. it's just like an element without an event.

So here is the code.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Confirm(ctl, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Confirm Logout?",
                text: "Do you really want to log this Account out?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                closeOnConfirm: true,
                closeOnCancel: true
            },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**ASPX**

```
    <li class="nav-item">
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogout" CssClass="nav-link" runat="server" OnClick="btnLogout_Click" OnClientClick="return Confirm(this,event)"><i class="icon ion-android-exit"></i></asp:LinkButton></li>
```

**C#**

```
 protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Session.Abandon();
         Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Sweet alert work asynchronously, so your confirm function will always returns false as written, But why sweet alert itself is not displayed, I'm not sure, Is there any error in the browser console?

Comment: @MatJ , It does not have an error sir. but you are right. the message is not shown.

Answer (score 3):

OnClientClick waits bool result to invoke server event but Confirm methods return nothing. ( `function (isConfirm)` returns async.)

You could call server event on  `function (isConfirm)` manually like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Confirm(ctl, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: "Confirm Logout?",
            text: "Do you really want to log this Account out?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            closeOnCancel: true
        },
        function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
               _doPostBack('btnLogout', 'OnClick');
            } 
        });

       return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The sweet alert message is not shown, but it successfully destroy the session